# How to get white (or other) color on FBTERM and CURSES without scrambling BOX drawing characters?

Tags: python, ncurses, framebuffer, terminfo

#### My question & current states:

I'm writing TUI software that is on [`fbterm`](https://github.com/sfzhi/fbterm) using [`python-curses`](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html) library.

- My objective here is to get some colors, most importantly **PURE WHITE** color.
- My current state: Instead of white, I'm getting somewhat gray color (not full brightness).
- Or If get white full brightness, I got my boxes (rectangles) get scrambled up

---

#### How I set color in python-curses:

I initialed color pair as below ([documentation here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.html?highlight=init_pair#curses.init_pair)), & used this pair of color all over my code:

```
    curses.init_pair(1, curses.COLOR_BLACK, curses.COLOR_WHITE)
```

It's not full white, I've seen full white in this display.

---

#### My guess what is happening:

Note: if you examined the black white values, those are 0 7 respectively.

```
>>> import curses
>>> print(curses.COLOR_BLACK, curses.COLOR_WHITE)
0 7
```

And when list out the available color on fbterm with `for i in {0..255}; do echo -ne "\E[2;$i}$i "; done; tput sgr0; echo` ([read from this thread](https://superuser.com/a/1108398/1605117) or just see the image). 0=black, 7=gray, 15=white

So, when my python is trying to send a white color (`python-curses` thinks white is 7) and gives to `fbterm`. `fbterm` receives 7 and thinks it is gray.

---

#### What things I've tried so far:

##### 1st-Try. set my white in color pair to 15:

My rationale: If `python-curses` send 15 to `fbterm`, it might think it is a white.

```
    curses.init_pair(1, curses.COLOR_BLACK, 15)
```

with this I come to following 2 results:

- if executed within `fbterm`, it get err: `_curses.error: init_pair() returned ERR`
- if executed from my laptop (`ssh`-ed), Software is working and white is more WHITE.

###### My guess on 1st try:

These 2 different outputs, might be caused different environmental variables:

- my laptop (on `lxterminal`): `$TERM` is `xterm-256color`
- on the device (on `fbterm`): `$TERM` is `linux`

##### 2nd-Try. set `TERM` variable to `fbterm`

My rationale: `fbterm` didn't set correct env variables -> can't use 256 colors. (below is from man page):

> ... By default, FbTerm sets environment variable "TERM" to value "linux", user need
> run "TERM=fbterm /path/to/program" to enable 256 color mode.

So I set manually executed `TERM=fbterm` (or `TERM=fbterm python3 main.py`), and executed my python code.
It shows full-bright white color, but texts are all scrambled:

```
 ÚÄÄÄÄÄ¿
 ³Meas.³
 ÀÄÄÄÄÄÙ ÚÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄ¿ÚÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄ¿
 ÚÄÄÄÄÄ¿ ³1-shot      ³³n-shot      ³
 ³Setup³ ³            ³³            ³
 ÀÄÄÄÄÄÙ ³            ³³            ³
 ÚÄÄÄÄÄ¿ ³            ³³            ³
 ³Data ³ ÀÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÙÀÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÙ
 ÀÄÄÄÄÄÙ
 ÚÄÄÄÄÄ¿
 ³About³ ÚÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄ¿ÚÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄ¿
 ÀÄÄÄÄÄÙ ³Target      ³³Weather     ³
 ÚÄÄÄÄÄ¿ ³            ³³            ³
 ³Sys. ³ ÀÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÙÀÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÙ
 ÀÄÄÄÄÄÙ
```

###### My guess on 2nd-try: NO IDEA

It seems characters like `|` `-` (and 90 deg thingy) for drawing boxes are scrambled, but the actual text-strings are OK.

/ps: these rectangles were drawn by `window.box()` which it self generated by `curses.newwin()`/

---

Can you help me to get color here? without scrambling my text?.

What Should  I try next?

/P.S Reason of trying get PURE WHITE: is to increase contrast to black color parts
for visibility.
(the device (which is handheld) is going to be used in daylight/outside).
Also, tips for better visibility are welcome. Thank you.
/

Can you help me to get color here? without scrambling my text?.

Comment: plugging in various `TERM` values won't get you anywhere.  To craft an improved terminal description for fbterm (looks like a dead project) you'll have to read the source code and test each change.

Answer (score 0):

According to its documentation, fbterm supports a variant of xterm's 256-color extension:

```
256 COLOR EXTENSION
       FbTerm  supports  xterm's 256 color mode extension. The first 16 colors
       are the default terminal colors. Additionally, there's  a  6x6x6  color
       cube,  and  24  grayscale tones. But xterm's 256 color escape sequences
       conflict with the linux sequences implemented by FbTerm, so private es‐
       cape sequences were introduced to support this feature:

           ESC [ 1 ; n }                   set foreground color to n (0 - 255)
           ESC [ 2 ; n }                   set background color to n (0 - 255)
           ESC  [  3 ; n ; r ; g ; b }       set color n to (r, g, b) ,  n, r,
       g, b all in (0 - 255)

       A new terminfo database entry named "fbterm" was  added  to  use  these
       private  sequences,  all program based on terminfo should work with it.
       By default, FbTerm sets environment variable "TERM" to value  "fbterm".
       Alternatively, the "TERM" variable can be set to "linux", in which case
       the 256 color mode will be unavailable.
```

With the xterm 256-color palette, your **pure white** is color number 15:

[image: fbterm's copy of xterm color-test]

ncurses provides a terminal description for [`fbterm`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#tic-fbterm), which you may find in the complete terminal database, e.g., "ncurses-term".

Neither "linux" (with 8 colors) nor "xterm-256color" (different escape sequences needed for both color **and** line-drawing) will work for *fbterm*.  Use infocmp to show the differences.